# If an element has been positioned using transform: translate can it be moved vertically using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

According to W3Schools, “The top property affects the vertical position of a positioned element. This property has no effect on non-positioned elements”

While https://developer.Mozilla.org says that transform:  translate results in a transform-function data type.

Does this mean that I can’t reposition an element vertically using JavaScript once I’ve given it an initial position using *transform: translate*?

It seems like you can’t *reliably* reposition an image. In this code I create a green div at 206 pixels. Then I use JavaScript to create an image in a div, using transform. Then I reposition the image to 206 pixels, so the top should be exactly aligned with the top of the green div. You can see from the screenshot that it’s well below the div. How can I overcome this problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="general.css">

<style>

figure {display: block;
        border-width:thin;
}
figcaption {background-color:yellow;}

#img1 {
  background: url("bates-sprite.jpeg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  object-fit: none;
  object-position: 0 0;
  width:  816px; // full size 3264
  height: 612px; // full size 2448
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<main>

<figure id="fig1">
    <figcaption>Camberley Mail</figcaption>
    <p id="para">Text to go with picture.</p>
</figure>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 206px; color: white; background-color: green;">===   206px   ===</div>

<script>
"use strict";
showBigImg(1);
function showBigImg(figNum) {
    // Get the figure caption
    const figcap = document.getElementById("fig" + figNum).firstElementChild;

    var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
    tempDiv.innerHTML =
    '<' + 'img id="img' + figNum + '" ' +
              'src="bates-sprite.jpeg"' +
              'style="height: 100vh; ' +
              'transform: translate(' + "48px" + ',1000px) ' +
                          'scale(2,2);">';

    figcap.appendChild (tempDiv);  /* Append image to the
                                  figcaption */

/*******************************************************/

    const img = document.getElementById ('img' + figNum);
    img.style.position = 'absolute';
    img.style.top = "-206px";

/*******************************************************/
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot showing result of code]

Comment: The link you posted... can you post a more specific one? Also, regarding your question, have you tried to experiment? What were your conclusions? Also, please avoid using w3schools as a source of best practices.

Comment: I didn’t intend to post a link. Apple’s software converted what I wrote into a link. However I found this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate

Comment: Translate is irrelevant. Test it yourself. Use form `transform: translate(100px, 100px)` and then: `position: relative; top: 200px;` Hope you'll answer your own question by doing so. I'm pretty sure you were just missing the `position` property (with value other than the default `static`).

Comment: Re "`width:  816px; // full size 3264`": `//` is not a valid comment character sequence in CSS (only the C-style one is, `/*  */`). This is also indicated by the weird ***syntax highlighting***. It *will* break in some browsers (e.g., it may ignore all or part of the rest of the CSS (terminate parsing)).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was being caused by using *transform: scale*.

I solved it by using *transform-origin: top left;*.